# Files writable by PHP even though CHMOD is 555?

Tags: php, apache, chmod

I've got a new server and when using my php script, I'm able to write files and detect them as being writable even though CHMOD has them as 555 or 755. Is there an apache module or php.ini that is making this possible? Is this a security problem?

Comment: Who is the files' owner?

Comment: Is the directory writable?  If so, the script will be allowed to remove the file completely, then recreate it.

Comment: Also, what user is the PHP process running under?

Comment: Also, what's the files group? And what user/group is running Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What filesystem is your server/volume using?

Some filesystems use different permission schemes, like Access Control Lists in addition to or instead of Unix permissions.  For example, you might be using AFS or OpenAFS (Andrew File System) which uses ACL's, in which case you'd have to enter a completely different command to change access.  Ask your network administrator; they should be able to answer that.  Or you  can try running

```
df -T
```

to see what that gives you.

Comment: It ended up being an apache module that was forcing all the files to be writable by php. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on file permissions here:

http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml

That should give you a clue about whats going on.

It doesn't have to be a security hole, file permissions are server side, but if people can upload files they can theoretically, potentially inflict harm by somehow getting their own code running on your server....

Comment: So why is a `555` permission (`r-x`) giving the process write access exactly?

Comment: reasons can vary depending on file owner, user that started php process what groups the user belongs to etc... unlikely but possible scenario is that the admin started the server with a root account and somehow left the process running under that user... it is pretty vague :)